# Appium launching the script on the connected real device (android) instead of the emulator already opened

Tags: python, android, selenium, pycharm, appium-android

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    desired_cap = {
        "platformName": "android",
        "deviceName": "emulator-5554",
        "appPackage": "com.project.PROJECT",
        "appActivity": ".SplashActivity",
        "automatorName": "UiAutomator2",
    }
```

Even though the emulator is declared within the capabilities, if I have an android phone connected AT THE SAME TIME, appium/pycharm will run the testing script on the real device and not on the emulator (as I intended).
This issue is not a blocker because if I disconnect the real device the script will run correctly.

Comment: 1- Connect your android phone to your computer 2- Type "adb devices" on your command prompt. 3- Tell us what you see there.

Comment: Already checked this... tried to change the names and is not working

**ce0616068154900105      device
emulator-5554   device**

I declared the emulator-5554 for testing and it still uses the real device